# facebook login and single instance launch mode

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

My app currently has launch mode as single instance. I wanted to include a facebook login into it. But facebook login works only when the launch mode is not single instance.

Is there any way that I can keep my working code with launch mode as single instance and change for the facebook login alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH` as the solution because this disables the very useful Single Sign On feature completely. Make call to authorize method with activity code `FACEBOOK.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH mFacebook.authorize(activity, permissions, activityCode, listener);`.

You can find a detailed explanation of this on my blog [Here](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/)